# Why can't I specify version in Update-Package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

This has to be a bug:

`Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall -Version 6.0.0.0`

Error:

```
    Update-Package : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall -Version 6.0.0.0
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Update-Package], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

Comment: As we discussed and for anyone else that might run across this question, the `-Reinstall` and `-Version` parameters cannot both be used with `Update-Package`.  When you pass `-Reinstall` the version will be the same version that is already installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the version.  Maybe it should be `6.0.1`?

`Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall -Version 6.0.1`

**EDIT**: Version not required since you included "*Reinstall*"
`Update-Package -Reinstall Newtonsoft.Json`

**EDIT**: Install specific version (leave out `-Version` to default to latest version)
    `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.1`

**EDIT**: Update to a specific version
`Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.1`

Comment: When you use `-Reinstall` with `Update-Package` it uninstalls then reinstalls the same version. I've edited the answer to remove the version entirely.

Comment: What if I want to install a specific version?

Comment: You can use `Install-Package` with the `-Version` parameter (or omit `-Version` to get the latest version).  Answer edited.

Comment: yeah, man, but I don't want to install it into any new project, I simply want to reinstall it in all project where it's currently installed but specifying a specific version. Maybe there is no direct way of doing this

Comment: My question has no answer or should have been asked in a different way, it should be deleted.

Comment: I see now. I think the only flaw is that it won't reinstall where that version is already installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98927/discussion-between-morpheus-and-space-monkey).